# Getting unknown property: Da\User\Module::isGuest yii2-usuario

Tags: php, yii2, yii2-basic-app, yii2-user, yii2-rbac

I'm install 2amigos/yii2-usuario:~1.5.1 on a yii2-basic-template, using https://yii2-usuario.readthedocs.io/en/latest/. However, it returns this error (Getting unknown property: Da\User\Module::isGuest yii2-usuario) in any view.
My config/console.php:

```
'components' => [
...
        'authManager'  => [
            'class'=> 'yii\rbac\DbManager',
        ],
...
],
'controllerMap' => [
        'migrate' => [
            'class' => \yii\console\controllers\MigrateController::class,
            'migrationPath' => [
                '@app/migrations',
                '@yii/rbac/migrations', // Just in case you forgot to run it on console (see next note)
            ],
            'migrationNamespaces' => [
                'Da\User\Migration',
            ],
        ],
    ],
```

My config/web.php:

```
'components' => [
  ...
  'user' => [
           'class' => Da\User\Module::class,
           'classMap' => [
                'User' => app\models\User::class,
            ],
 ],
 'authManager'  => [
            'class' => 'yii\rbac\DbManager',
  ],
  'view' => [
            'theme' => [
                'pathMap' => [
                     '@Da/User/resources/views' => '@app/views/user'
                ]
            ]
   ]
],
```

I managed to solve it with help.
Follow the line:
Remove : config/web.php

```
'user' => [
            'identityClass' => 'app\models\Users',
            'enableAutoLogin' => true,
            'enableSession' => true,

        ],

 'user-management' => [
            'class' => 'webvimark\modules\UserManagement\UserManagementModule',
            'on beforeAction'=>function(yii\base\ActionEvent $event) {
                if ( $event->action->uniqueId == 'user-management/auth/login' ){
                    $event->action->controller->layout = 'loginLayout.php';
                };
            },
        ],
add into config/web.php:
'components' =>[ ...
'authManager'  => [
            'class' => 'yii\rbac\DbManager',
        ],
'view' => ['theme' => [ 'pathMap' => ['@Da/User/resources/views' => '@app/views/user']]] //If your view is modified.
]
'modules' => ['user' => [
            'class' => \Da\User\Module::class,
            'allowAccountDelete' => true,
            'enableRegistration' => false,
            'administratorPermissionName' => 'user-management']
...]
``
```

Comment: my repository: [**https://github.com/miriambarroso/hocom** ].

Comment: And config/console.php: add: `components=>[ 'authManager'  => [
            'class'=> 'yii\rbac\DbManager',
        ],
        'view' => [
            'theme' => [
                'pathMap' => [
                    '@Da/User/resources/views' => '@app/views/user'
                ]
            ]
        ]]
...
 'controllerMap' => [
        'migrate' => [
            'class' => \yii\console\controllers\MigrateController::class,
            'migrationNamespaces' => [
                'Da\User\Migration',
            ],
        ],
    ],
`

Comment: And config/console.php: and remove: `'modules'=>[
        'user-management' => [
            'class' => 'webvimark\modules\UserManagement\UserManagementModule',
            'controllerNamespace'=>'vendor\webvimark\modules\UserManagement\controllers', // To prevent yii help from crashing
        ],
    ],`